# Symbolic Representation of Minimum

Tags: python, wolfram-mathematica, symbolic-math, algebra

`(2x - c)**2` has a minimum at `x = c/2`.  However, I have a much more complicated algebraic expression that I need to find the minimum of.  And I need that minimum in terms of symbols, not an actual number.  Specifically:

```
m(1-n)/(m(1-n) + (1-m)n) - x/(x(1-y) + (1-x)y)
```

where `m = (x + (1-x)(1-c))` and `n = (y + (1-y)(1-c))` for some constant c.  x, y are both in [0, 1].

What would be a good way to go about finding this?  I'd like to find value of x that maximizes this in terms of y and c.  Even for y=0 would still be really great.  I was trying to use Wolfram-Mathematica but it was not cooperating.

Comment: y=0 is easy; plugging in x=1 reduces that absolute value to 0.

Comment: Oops, I have no idea why I put absolute value bars around that.

Comment: your expression goes to `-Infinity` at `x=y=1`

Answer (score 0):

I got confused, your title says minimum and the text says maximum.  You can indeed find a maximum :

```
 Maximize[{expr, 0 <= x <= 1, 0 <= y <= 1}, {x, y}]
```

..This takes a few minutes..

> [image]

oddly, the values `{0,1/2,Infinity}` are correct, however the `x,y` locations are not.  It should be `x==0 OR y==0 for c==1` and `x==0 AND y==0 for c<1` ..   Evidently `Maximize` is not very good at describing a solution which is not unique.